# Blender 2.6: Changing the Resolution (Rings/Segments) of a UVSphere's

Tags: 3d, blender

I know that it's possible to change the resolution (I mean the rings and the segments) of a UVSphere by pressing `[F6]` and changing some arguments.

But what if I add a UVSphere to my canvas at first, then I do something else in the meantime and *not till then* I want to change the resultion of the UVSphere which I added *before*. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering, why you need that?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing would be to remove it and add a new UV sphere. Once the sphere has been placed, the options for changing it's attributes is gone. The only option I know of is to add a subdivide surface modifier to your sphere. That will subdivide all the quads, but it essentially only allows you to double your rings and segments, not increase them separately or by a factor less than 2. So to easily replace an existing UV sphere, you can do the following:

1. Select the UV sphere you want
2. Press Shift+S and select `Cursor to Selected`
3. Press X and confirm delete
4. Press Shift+A and select `Mesh->UVSphere`
5. Choose your arguments